# Почему карта не передвигается в стороны на планшете?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Скажите почему [вот здесь](http://www.spravka-azov.ru/test/userreg.php) карта не перемещается в стороны на планшете? Планшет, правда, нестандартный, TouchPad на базе WebOS, на андроиде все нормально. Но вот [здесь](http://www.spravka-azov.ru/test/firm.php?id=1764) например карта в Точпаде перемещается нормально. Может, кто знает, как сделать, чтобы перемещалась на планшете в первом случае? Помощь нужна срочно, буду очень признателен.

Comment: с этим вопросом вам не сюда

Comment: Почему? Вопрос-то заключается в коде.

Comment: А если вы, скажем, из торрента игру скачаете, и она у вас не будет устанавливаться, вы тоже  сюда напишете - ведь вопрос наверняка тоже заключается в коде?

Comment: Код карты на яваскрипте? На яваскрипте. Тег яваскрипт на Хэшкоде имеется? Имеется. Какие вопросы еще? Может быть самым правильным будет задать на ОСМ-форуме, но и здесь вполне уместно, по-моему.

Comment: уважаемый, вы в таком тоне с вашими подчиненными разговаривайте, если у вас они есть. А что касается вопроса, то пораскиньте мозгами, если есть чем раскидывать - вы предлагаете, чтобы те, чьей помощи вы тут ищете, поковырялись в JS-коде на том сайте с ПК, а потом еще отладили бы его с планшета, причем, желательно той же модели что у вас? Причем, еще не факт, что для понимания причин проблемы достаточно только клиентского JS на странице.  что  Ну что же, удачи вам в ваших ожиданиях - я смотрю, тут просто толпа желающих вам помочь в этом

Comment: Молодец, нахамил, обложил, наумничал, собой доволен, иди с миром.

Comment: Ваша проблема заключена в не кроссбраузерной реализации кода.  

------------

Можете не расчитывать на более развернутый ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

Строка 16 в CSS. Уберите **width: 770px;** или строка 905, в **@mediа screen and (max-width:480px)** добавить правило для **#map {width: auto;}**

P.S. Такие вещи можно и самому легко отлаживать, используя какой-нибудь соответствующий инструмент. Например, [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: А почему карта стала урезанная? А на планшете все равно не двигается.

Comment: @Aviko - вам не фриланс

Comment: да мне не фриланс, мне спросить хочется

Comment: В вопросе про эксплорер комменты почему-то заблокировали, поэтому говорю здесь. Предложение деловое, меня вообще-то Андрей зовут и я не по той части, чтобы мужикам неделовые предложения делать, если что.

Comment: @Aviko, укажите в своем профиле контактные данные.

Comment: Да вроде указал, в редактировании профиля почта указана... andrey.godservant(собака)yandex.ru